# Неявная декларация

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если в `a.c` нет объявления функции, которая определена в `b.c`, но при этом в `a.c` происходит вызов такой функции, то что происходит?

Интересует язык `C`.

В описанной ситуации `MinGW-w64` говорит:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function '...'
```

Я так понимаю, что в этом случае происходит неявная декларация (объявление) функции?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что код работает только потому, что автоматически сформированная сигнатура совпадает с реальной сигнатурой? Если она не совпадет, то это неопределенное поведение?

Хочу разобраться подробнее.

Comment: При вызове функции без объявления компилятор полагает, что она возвращает `int`, типы ее параметров совпадают с типами передаваемых аргументов и она принимает столько аргументов, сколько ей передают в точке вызова. В принципе, тут реально важен только тип возвращаемого значения.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

К современному С эта тема имеет отношение только в контексте вызова функции, *объявленной без прототипа*.

Современный язык С запрещает вызов необъявленных функций. Начиная с C99 все функции должны быть объявлены пред вызовом. Вызов необъявленной функции - это constraint violation, т.е. ошибка. Все остальное - самодеятельность вашего компилятора, к языку С никакого отношения не имеющая.

В устаревшем стандарте C89/90 вызов необъявленных функций разрешался. Компилятор пытался "угадать" тип функции на основе количества и типов передаваемых аргументов (типы аргументов после default argument promotions), а также подразумевал возвращаемое значение типа `int`.

```
short s = 0;
/* Вызов необъявленной функции */
foo(s, 5, 3.14f, "H");
/* Компилятор предполагает:
   int foo(int, int, double, char *) */
```

Современный С ведет себя по этой же схеме, если объявление функции сделано, но без прототипа (т.наз. "объявления в K&R стиле"). Угадывать тип возвращаемого значения больше не нужно, т.к. он явно присутствует в объявлении, а угадывание типов параметров делается по-старому. Объявления без прототипа являются deprecated.

Если "угаданный" тип функции несовместим с фактическим - поведение не определено.  При попытке вызова variadic функции без предварительного объявления поведение не определено в любом случае.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за помощь.